# WatchOS3 Is it possible to stream audio and video from iPhone Camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-watch, watchos-3

i'm asking a question :

Is it possible to stream (real-time) video/audio captured from iPhone camera directly to an Apple Watch 2 (WatchOS3) ?
Something like the camera button on the apple watch that automatically starts camera app on iPhone, but video and Audio.

thanks..

Victor